# How to write an NPM module that uses multiple files?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a simple local command-line module that I want to use in 2 different ways (basically different defaults), but it uses the same core logic, so I want to extract that logic into a third entity and use that from the two entry points.

I have everything working with two `bin` command scripts, but each file has its own copy of the logic to run, and I am not sure how to pull this duplicated code out into a third file within the same module. I figure I could do it by creating an entire separate module and loading it with `require()`, but I would rather just keep it together since it's tightly coupled.

The structure is like this:

```
bin\
  cmdone.js
  cmdtwo.js
core.js
package.json
```

I would like to move the logic, which currently exists in both `cmdone.js` and `cmdtwo.js`, into `core.js` and reference it from the two files in `bin`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correct, then what you need is [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) function of `nodejs`

Comment: That's basically correct. I already knew about require, but I didn't know or realize that it could be used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some more poking around, I discovered that this works:

```
const test = require('../core.js');
```

I suppose I misunderstood the distinction between Node modules and NPM packages. I was basically equating the two, but it seems that you can create and use modules entirely within packages, they don't have to be one-to-one.